# Save Activedocument to Different Name/Directory Without Changing Activedocument

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a .docm file that is being used as a template-file (parent file) and I would like to create child-files (with different names and directories) directly from this file without changing the name/directory of the parent-file. I tried the following:

```
Dim parent_document As New Word.Document
Dim child_document As New Word.Document
Set parent_document = ActiveDocument
Set child_document = parent_document
child_document.SaveAs2 doc_path & "\" & item & ".docx"
```

Unfortunately the name/directory of the active document changes to that of the child-document. I thought by using the New keyword I am creating separate instances of the activedocument. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: So why are you using a document as a template, instead of using a real template? If you did that you wouldn't have the problem.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the response. Even if the parent document is a .dotm file the ActiveDocument changes (name & path changes) after the .SaveAs2 Method is invoked. I want to keep the template the ActiveDocument  after saving so I can rapidly make child-documents. The only way I can think of doing this is to create a new document with the Documents.Add Method and use the .dotm file as a template.

Comment: «The only way I can think of doing this is to create a new document with the Documents.Add Method and use the .dotm file as a template» Which is exactly what you *should* be doing.